# Raspberry Pi 4 , Video Calling Mic Issue Android 13

Tags: webcam, microphone

I am using an Raspberry Pi 4 ,8GB board and have installed lineage-20.0-20230321-UNOFFICIAL-KonstaKANG (Android-13) .

All thing are working fine but stuck in Video Calling via IMO, Jitsi, Zoom and other recommended VC Apps as it is unable to deliver any sound.

I Have tried 3 different Webcam of Logitech which of course comes with MIC but no one able to deliver MIC sound

I also attach one USB Mic of Zebronics  as well... which is recognized while voice calling and voice recording  but still not helping in VC.

kindly let me know is it a known issues or  some DIY can help the cause .